# oncreate is called when Dont keep activities is set

Tags: android, performance

Can anyone please tell me what should I do in the following scenario. 
I have four activities Ac1, Ac2, Ac3 and Ac4, each activity has a Cancel button, which when pressed should take to the Ac1. Also back button should traverse back to previous activity.
Ac1 is the start and Ac4 is the end in the flow.

I had used FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK in the Cancel button and in the last Ac4, to go back to Ac1. But this was not working as expected.
So to do this I have a broadcast register to stop the activities when Cancel button is pressed in any of the activities. So on recieving the broadcast reciever I would call finish() to close the stacked activities.
Everything works fine when the developer options is not set(Dont keep activties). When this option is set, 
1. Ac1 is moved to Ac2. 
2. Ac2 is started, but Ac1 is cleared.
3. Ac2 is moved to Ac3
4. Ac3 is started and Ac2 is cleared.
5. When Cancel is called, broadcast reciever is sent to close activity.
6. Surprisingly Im seeing Ac2 is called, instead of Ac1. I could see onCreate of Ac2 is being called.

I dont know how to get rid of this situtation. Can anyone help me out of this situtation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadcast is a bit overkill and FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK is not what you are looking for.
Try to call Ac1 in cancel button with `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);`

Comment: Correct me if Im wrong.. FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP is fine but FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP is not useful when Dont keep activities is set. As you said I will give a try.. Thanks for the help

Comment: 'don't keep activities' is a developer option. You don't rely on it, it just helps you to check if your application handles low-memory situations correctly. FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP tells the system not to create another instance of activity if there is one on the top of the stack.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, you want to support a stack of activities that may grow from A1 up to A4. The user may use the back button to transition back from A(N+1) to A(N), and may hit a Cancel button to clear the entire stack from A(N) down to A2, leaving only A1.

(Sorry if that's no clearer than your original description :-)

My first approach would be to use [`Activity.startActivityForResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) to start the child activities. When a child activity exits -- whether by the back button, the Cancel button, or a normal exit -- that child's immediate parent can look at the result code that is passed back to [`onActivityResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29), and terminate itself if the result code indicates that the Cancel button was selected.

Have you tried anything like this?

Comment: I cant use the startActivityforResult, because the app crashes when Dont keep activities is set.

Answer (score 0):

try to link cancel button to ac1 try to clear old activity stack and jump to ac1

```
Intent intent  = new Intent(this, ac1.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);        
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
class Activity2{

    int KILL_ACTIVITY=555;

    startActivityForResult(new Intent(Activity2.this,Activity3.class), 0);

    @Override onActivityResult(... , int result){
        if(result==KILL_ACTIVITY)
            finish();
    }
```

### }

```
class Activity3{

    int KILL_ACTIVITY=555;
    @Override onClick(View v){
        if(v.getId()==R.id.button){
            setResult(KILL_ACTIVITY);
            finish();
        }
    }


    startActivityForResult(new Intent(Activity3.this,Activity4.class), 0);

    @Override onActivityResult(... , int result){
        if(result==KILL_ACTIVITY)
            finish();
    }
}
```